# rails scope multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, scope

I have a `User` model. My goal is to have a scope that returns `users` found by selected field .

Like

```
scope :starts_with, ->(filter, starts_with) { where("? like ?", "#{filter}", "#{starts_with}%")}
```

This is in my view:

```
<%= select_tag(:filter, options_for_select([["Name", "name"],
                                                  ["E-mail", "email"]],
                                                  "name"), {:multiple => true}) %>
<%= text_field_tag :starts_with, params[:starts_with] %>
```

**UPD** I'm calling scope like that:

```
def index
  @users = User.starts_with(params[:filter, :starts_with]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 40)
end
```

At the moment it shows an error `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments(1 for 0)`

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You'll need to show us where you call the scope, your controller action etc... And also give us more details about what you want to achieve, some context would be nice.

Comment: You are missing some code to help you. Please paste the line, where the scope is called (if the error message is related to the scope).

Comment: Sure, updated scope call and the error!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code in your action with:

```
def index
  @users = User.starts_with(params[:filter], params[:starts_with]).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 40)
end
```

**What's going on**

In your original call you do `User.starts_with(params[:filter, :starts_with])`. Notice the `params[:filter, :starts_with]`. You are passing two arguments to the `[]` method of the params `hash`. This method only takes one argument. Check out the ruby doc for more info:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D

params is a `hash` like any other `hash` you might want to use in your app or any ruby code. So, instead of doing `params[:filter, :starts_with]` that is not authorized, you need to ask for the value of the `:filter` key and `:starts_with` key separately and pass them as arguments to your scope like this:

```
User.starts_with(params[:filter], params[:starts_with])
```

Comment: mlainez, thank you! Now it works, but... it doesn't. It searches correctly in the only case: when the query consists of a one letter. If more letters, selection returns empty. I don't understand why.

Comment: What's interesting: if I make a scope with 1 parameter, it searches good: `scope :starts_with, ->(starts_with) { where("name like ?", "#{starts_with}%")}`, which makes a query in log `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE (name like 'Ma%') LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0`. But if I scope with multiple parameters, like `scope :starts_with, ->(filter, starts_with) { where("? LIKE ?", filter, "#{starts_with}%")}` it doesn't search more than 1 letter (SQL in the log is `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ('name' like 'Ma%') LIMIT 40 OFFSET 0`). I think it's all because of quotes, but how to get rid of them?

Comment: Hope I described clearly! I meant quotes around `name` in SQL query =)

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this solution but you could interpolate the first parameter like this `where("#{filter} like ?", "#{starts_with}%")`. Does this change anything? I'll think about it and try to come up with something better. Maybe using Arel.

Comment: No, that doesn't change. Tried also to change "name" into :name in the view.

Comment: Ok, please update your question with more information on the remaining problems so that everyone can see it. Hopefully someone else will jump in.

Comment: Figured it out. Should've been like this: `scope :starts_with, ->(filter, starts_with) { where("#{filter} LIKE ?", "#{starts_with}%")}` (there's no quotes in this case). Accepting your's as an answer. Thank you, mate!

Comment: Isn't that what I wrote in my comment? :) Anyway, I'm glad it got solved. Thanks.

Comment: *facepalm* You're right, it was my fault) At that time I've changed another line of code and that's why your advice didn't work )) I wasn't attentive enough! Thanks again! :)